# How to use Postgres with JSON to create objects with 3 levels

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

Suppose I had rows like

| id | group1 | group2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 55 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 66 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 66 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 77 |

I'm looking to group on id so I'd have two rows with

```
| id       | json         
| -------- | -------------
| 5        | {1: {2: 55, 3: 66}, 2: {1: 66}}        
| 4        | {1: {3: 77}}
```

I've tried combinations of `JSON_OBJECT_AGG` wrapped in `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` with the results going to `JSON_AGG`. That is almost giving me what I want. The items are in an array. Each object in the array has only one outer key and all the inner keys are as expected. If I could combine all the objects in the array or just build the objects correctly, either way would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_object_agg()` twice, first aggregating by `id, group1` and then grouping only by `id`:

```sql
select id, jsonb_object_agg(group1, json) as json
from (
    select 
        id,
        group1,
        jsonb_object_agg(group2, value) as json
    from my_table
    group by id, group1
    ) s
group by id
```

Test it in [db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/gE-xbqQ3)

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you!